# Find the minimum in a mixed list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog, I am just learning about lists and I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045367/getting-the-minimum-value-of-a-list). The answer works perfect for a list of integers.

```
minimo([X], X) :- !.
minimo([X,Y|Tail], N):-
    ( X > Y ->
        minimo([Y|Tail], N)
    ;
        minimo([X|Tail], N)
    ).
```

How can I change this code to get the smallest int from a mixed list?

This

```
sint([a,b,3,2,1],S)
```

should give an answer:

```
S=1
```

Comment: What if there is no integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think the proposed implementation is very *elegant*: here they pass the minimum found element thus far by constructing a new list each time. Using an additional parameter (we call an *accumulator*) is usually the way to go (and is probably more efficient as well).

In order to solve the problem, we first **have to find an integer**. We can do this like:

```
sint([H|T],R) :-
    integer(H),
    !,
    sint(T,H,R).
sint([_|T],R) :-
    sint(T,R).
```

So here we check if the *head* `H` is an `integer/1`. If that is the case, we call a predicate `sint/3` (not to be confused with `sint/2`). Otherwise we call recursively `sint/2` with the *tail* `T` of the list.

Now we still need to define `sint/3`. In case we have reached the end of the list `[]`, we simply return the minum found thus far:

```
sint([],R,R).
```

Otherwise there are two cases:

- the head `H` is an integer and smaller than the element found thus far, in that case we perform recursion with the head as new current minimum:

  ```
  sint([H|T],M,R):
      integer(H),
      H < M,
      !,
      sint(T,H,R).
  ```
- otherwise, we simply ignore the head, and perform recursion with the tail `T`.

  ```
  sint([_|T],M,R) :-
      sint(T,M,R).
  ```

We can put the recursive clauses in an if-then-else structure. Together with the earlier defined predicate, the full program then is:

```
sint([H|T],R) :-
    integer(H),
    !,
    sint(T,H,R).
sint([_|T],R) :-
    sint(T,R).

sint([],R,R).
sint([H|T],M,R):
    (
     (integer(H),H < M)
     -> sint(T,H,R)
     ;  sint(T,M,R)
    ).
```

The advantage of this approach is that *filtering* and *comparing* (to obtain the minimum) is done at the same time, so we only iterate once over the list. This will usually result in a performance boost since the "control structures" are only executed once: more is done in an iteration, but we only iterate once.

We can **generalize** the approach by making the *filter* generic:

```
filter_minimum(Filter,[H|T],R) :-
    Goal =.. [Filter,H],
    call(Goal),
    !,
    filter_minimum(Filter,T,H,R).
filter_minimum(Filter,[_|T],R) :-
    filter_minimum(Filter,T,R).

filter_minimum(_,[],R,R).
filter_minimum(Filter,[H|T],M,R) :-
    Goal =.. [Filter,H],
    (
     (call(Goal),H < M)
     -> filter_minimum(Filter,T,H,R)
     ;  filter_minimum(Filter,T,M,R)
    ).
```

You can then call it with:

```
filter_minimum(integer,[a,b,3,2,1],R).
```

to filter with `integer/1` and calculate the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

you could just ignore the problem, changing the comparison operator (>)/2 (a binary builtin predicate, actually) to the more general (@>)/2:

```
minimo([X], X) :- !.
minimo([X,Y|Tail], N):-
    ( X @> Y ->
        minimo([Y|Tail], N)
    ;
        minimo([X|Tail], N)
    ).

?- minimo([a,b,3,2,1],S).
S = 1.
```

Comment: This will also succeed for a list containing no integers, like `minimo([a])`.

Comment: I know... don't think it's a problem

Comment: I was thinking along these lines as well (s(X)) but it bothered me that the symmetrical solution wouldn't work if the problem were changed to maximum instead of minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a predicate that returns a list with the numbers and the use the above minimo/2 predicate:

```
only_numbers([],[]).
only_numbers([H|T],[H|T1]):-integer(H),only_numbers(T,T1).
only_numbers([H|T],L):- \+integer(H),only_numbers(T,L).

sint(L,S):-only_numbers(L,L1),minimo(L1,S).
```

Comment: `number/1` also accepts floats: `number(14.25)` succeeds.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem, thanks !!
 It may be better to use integer/1 instead of number/1...

Comment: and then, use include/3: `only_numbers(L,Ns) :- include(integer,L,Ns).`